# Touch not responding with UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a storyboard with a UINavigationViewController that holds a UITableView and a UIToolBar. The TableView populates well but doesn't respond when I touch a TableViewCell. It lits up but the selection doesn't persist and the handler function isn't called. When I make some sort of swipe over the cell it sometimes records the touch event and the handler is called. Looks like as if touchEvents aren't recognized or hold back. This is my setup:

[image]

[image]

The View component config of the NavigationView

[image]

The UITableView config

Remarkable is that if I touch the cell with 2 fingers it selects the cell...! So this handler gets called in that case:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.selectedWerkzaamheden = self.model.selectedWerkorder.werkbonWerkzaamheden;
    self.selectedWerkzaamheden = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.model.selectedWerkorder.werkbonWerkzaamheden];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                               initWithTarget:self
                               action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    [self.myTableView reloadData];
}

...

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.selectedWerkzaamheidIndex = indexPath.row;
    self.selectedWerkzaamheid = self.selectedWerkzaamheden[self.selectedWerkzaamheidIndex];
    self.trashBtn.enabled = TRUE;
}
```

The declaration file:

```
#import "LmxViewController.h"
#import "LmxDropDownDataVO.h"

@interface LmxWerkzaamheidViewController : LmxViewController <UITableViewDataSource>

@property NSString *faultTitle;
@property NSString *faultMessage;
@property IBOutlet UIButton *selectWerkzaamheidBtn;
@property LmxDropDownDataVO *selectedWerkzaamheid;
@property NSInteger selectedWerkzaamheidIndex;
@property NSMutableArray *selectedWerkzaamheden;
@property IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *submitBtn;
@property IBOutlet UITableView *werkzaamheidTableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *trashBtn;

- (IBAction)selectWerkzaamheid:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)saveWerkzaamheidWithWerkorder:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender;
@end
```

Might there be something wrong in the way I supply the cells?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSMutableArray *werkzaamheden = self.selectedWerkzaamheden;

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;

    NSInteger row = indexPath.row;
    LmxDropDownDataVO *data = (LmxDropDownDataVO *)werkzaamheden[row];
    cell.textLabel.text = data.naam;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Can you show what code you're expecting should be called.

Comment: why didnt you use didselectcell delegate method to call selectWerkzaamheid instead of making it an ibaction

Comment: @longbow sorry I copy/pasted the wrong function. Up above you see the right function.

Comment: Did you have any uigesturerecognizer add here? Or anything like it?

Comment: What are the subviews of cell? Have somethings like scroll,...? Try to create an empty cell and check does it works or not

Comment: Sometimes when you can't find a needle in a haystack you need to rebuild the haystack till you find the needle. I did. First build a working version of a tableview then integrated it with my application and started to add functionalities. Actually I should have found the bug by Anthu's provided suggestion, but I didn't.. Finally I found that there is a gesture component initiated but it is a UITapGestureRecognizer, which is used in class I duplicated my class from. It was catching the touch event before my Delegate class could. Next time I will post the complete class.. thx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was I did leave a piece of code in the viewDidLoad class that obscured the touch event of the table view cell.

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                   initWithTarget:self
                                   action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

Apparently this is blocking the touch events to reach the Table View Delegate function:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Thx for your contributions.